# Range slider error: 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, input, vuetify.js

I'm just trying to use a v-range-slider component from vuetify, but i don't know why it is throwing 'addEventListener' of undefined.

I'm doing a basic use of it and it keeps failing. Sometimes it works the first time but then breaks.

Here's [their doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders)

And [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ur9te5c4/3/)

```
VUE Component:

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      value1: [30, 60],
    }
  }
})
```

```
HTML Template:

<div id="app">
  <v-range-slider
    color="red"
     v-model="value1"
  ></v-range-slider>
</div>
```

I don't know what else can I do xD
Is someone facing the same problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the warning:

> vuetify.min.js:6 [Vuetify] Missing v-app or a non-body wrapping element with the [data-app] attribute

You just need to add a `v-app` wrapper in your example to make Vuetify work correctly

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsoLw6mc/)